# Getting Json formatted objects

Tags: json

Ok, so I have a big JSON file that has arrays and objects setup for controls for a google map project I am working on...looks like this:

```
{
"settings":
{



    "DEFAULT_MAP_SETTING":  "DEFAULT_MAP_SETTINGS",

    "DEFAULT_MAP_RES":      "county",
    "DEFAULT_MAP_CAT":      "popden"
},

"map_settings":
{
    "DEFAULT_MAP_SETTINGS":
    {
        "map_options":
        {
            "center":               [39.828175, -94.5795],
            "mapTypeId":            "TERRAIN",
            "streetViewControl":    false,
            "scrollwheel":          false,
            "overviewMapControl":   false,
            "mapTypeControl":       false,
            "zoom":                 4
        },


        "map_bounds":
        {
            "upper-left":           [98.70, -127.50],
            "lower-right":          [48.85, -55.90]
        },




    }

}
}
```

My question is how do I go about getting this data in json format as it has to be in json format to load up options and what not in google maps. For instance I have

```
var myMapOptions = {
            "zoom": 4,
            "minZoom" : 4,
            "scrollWheel" : false,
            "center": initialLoc,
            "mapTypeId": google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };

var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);
```

Which loads up the google map. But I cant figure out how to set myMapOptions with my big Json file. Every method that I know of returns the json data in strings and gets rid of the formatting. Like $.ajax in jQuery will go get the json for me but it strips it of its formatting.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery $.ajax() will automatically transform you JSON "file" into a javascript object if your request come back with a JSON header.

However you can override this by using dataType of $.ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

The previous script will alert you JSON file like you want.

**[Update]**
You can try to use eval():

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(data){
    var options = eval(data);
  }
});
```

In this case your data need to be executable by javascript.

**[Update 2]**
JsonP style, your json file need to looks like that:

```
var options = {
   "zoom": 4, "minZoom" : 4,
   "scrollWheel" : false,
   "center": new google.maps.LatLng(39.828175, -94.5795),
   "mapTypeId": google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

**Notice the "var options ="**

Your ajax request need to look like that:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);// will show your data as text
    eval(data); this will execute your "JSON file"

    //after eval you can now use options as a variable
    alert(options);
  }
});
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks man. Now the question is how to get the data saved in a variable to put into the new google map class. This is returning my data how I want but when I try to save it in a variable and pass into the google map class it refuses to work.

Comment: I got the data stored in the variable turning async off but when I pass the variable where the json object is stored into the google.maps.Map it doesnt work. However when I test with an alert the formatting returns correct.

Comment: I cut the json way down to simplify it:  { "zoom": 4, "minZoom" : 4, "scrollWheel" : false, "center": new google.maps.LatLng(39.828175, -94.5795), "mapTypeId": google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };    But when I pass this to the variable and try to load it into the google maps options it doesnt work - map doesnt load.   var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), jsonvariable);

Comment: Brandon so you don't need this as a TEXT format, you need jquery to parse it for you. So Change the dataType to "json". Now the value of data will be a javascript object, that you can pass to Google directly.

Comment: Thanks for all your help man, I really appreciate it. Tried changing the format to json and the program stops. Also tried keeping dataType set to text and use $.jsonPartse(data) and the same thing happened...any ideas?

Comment: You first json file is not valid, you have an extra comma after "map_bounds"{...} you can use http://jsonlint.com/ to make sure that you json is valid

Comment: Im not using the first json file anymore I simplified it and now am just using { "zoom": 4, "minZoom" : 4, "scrollWheel" : false, "center": new google.maps.LatLng(39.828175, -94.5795), "mapTypeId": google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };...however when I go to jsonlint it tells me the center and mapTypId values are invalid...how would I format those to be valid json? Is it even possible?

Comment: Thats the thing you cannot do that in json... one last thing you can try use dataType "script", I think it will eval your data into a script... OR use dataType text and in the success function do: var options = eval(data);

Comment: Ok, well it seems like my idea of having one large JSON file with all my data and settings in it is no going to work. Since you can't format certain things in json to work with google maps. Thanks for all your help zarbi!

Comment: Hey Brandon what you can do it's use JSONP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) I think you can work with that to do what you want.

Comment: hmmm ok I will try jsonp in the dataType and see what happens

Comment: no not in the dataType, jsonP is totally different. You should google it to see how you can use it in your case.

Comment: just got back to my desk, Ill see what I can do!

Comment: myMapOptions = eval(data). This returns undefined.

Comment: Ok went back and did it exactly how you described now its returning [object object] and i can access the interior data using dot syntax but how am I supposed to load the entire variable into theMap?

Comment: Im considering loading a .js script with all my object in there and doing it that way...May be able to get the same thing accomplished..what do you think?

Comment: Yes you can do the same thing by loading a .js with all your objects. It's what I called JsonP. To load the variable into your map i assume you have to do: var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);